# COM ApplicationClass.Documents.Open thread

Tags: c#, com, ms-word, document

I am using the Interop word ApplicationClass.Documents.Open method to open a word document.
In my application when I use the below statement it hangs: IE shows it's still loading but it never does anything.

```
_Document aDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(
    ref fileName, ref oMissing, ref readOnly, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref isVisible, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing);
```

I tried the same thing by creating a dummy website and it worked. The problem is it just does not open the word document in my application. Anything wrong in this code or is there something more I need to add to this?

I also see a thread which is created and executed but have no clue as to from where its originated.

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from your question, you are trying to open a Word document, using the Word application itself (via COM interop) on a Web server.

You should not do this. Word is not created to run in the context of a Windows service. That is, without user interface.

Probably Word is waiting for some response from the user, in a dialog box. But since you do not have a UI, this will not show.